# How to get the list of files (ls command) from bz2 archive?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

What is the Unix bash command to get the list of files (like `ls`) from archive file of type `.bz2` (without unzipping the archive)?

Answer (score 4):

First `bzip2`, `gzip`, etc compress only one file. So probably you have compressed `tar` file. To list the files you need command like:

```
tar tjvf file.bz2
```

This command uncompress the archive and test the content of `tar`.

Comment: @AdiEp, as I explain already if the file is `file.bz2` this mean the compressed file is `file`

Answer (score 0):

Note that bzip2 compresses each file, and a simple .bz2 file always contains a single file of the same name with the ".bz2" part stripped off. When using bzip2 to compress a file, there is no option to specify a different name, the original name is used and .bz2 appended. So there are no files, only 1 file. If that file is a tar archive, it can contain many files, and the whole contents of the .tar.bz2 file can be listed with "tar tf file.tar.bz2" without unpacking the archive.

Comment: This function gives the uncompressed filename, its size and the compression rate: bzlist(){ [[ ! -f "$1" ]] && echo "not a file: '$1'" && return; local d=$(mktemp -d); s=$(stat -c %s "$1")00; cp "$1" "$d" || return 2; bunzip2 "$d"/* || return 3; i=$(stat -c "%n %s" "$d"/* |sed "s@$d/@@"); echo "$i $((s/${i##* }))%"; rm -r "$d";}